# Metric on one-point compactification

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, notation, terminology

Is there a **standard** construction of a metric on one-point compactification of a proper metric space?

**Comments:**

- A metric space is **proper** if all bounded closed sets are compact.
- **Standard** means *found in literature*.

**From the answers  and comments:**

Here is a simplification of the construction given [here](https://www.jstor.org/pss/2047675)<sup>1</sup> (thanks to Jonas for ref).
Let $d$ be the original metric. Fix a point $p$ and set $h(x)=1/(1+d(p,x))$.
Then take the metric
$$\hat d(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),\,h(x)+h(y)\},\ \ \ \  \hat d(\infty,x)=h(x).$$

A more complicated construction is given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006137)<sup>2</sup> (thanks to LK for ref), some call it "sphericalization".
One takes
$$\bar d(x,y)=d(x,y)\cdot h(x)\cdot h(y),\ \ \ \  \bar d(\infty,x)=h(x).$$
The function $\bar d$ does not satisfies triangle inequality, but one can show that there is a metric $\rho$ such that $\tfrac14\cdot \bar d\le \rho\le \bar d$.

<sup>1</sup>Mandelkern, Mark. “Metrization of the One-Point Compactification.” Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 107, no. 4, American Mathematical Society, 1989, pp. 1111–15, https://doi.org/10.2307/2047675.

<sup>2</sup>Mario Bonk, Bruce Kleiner: *Rigidity for Quasi-Mobius group actions*

Comment: Is there a standard strictly increasing function from $\mathbb R\ge0$ to $[0,1)$?  If you make your metric finite in this way, I should think you would get a metric on the compactification by adding in the 1 for a distance to the point at infinity.  Not an answer, because I may be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard": found in literature or canonical w.r.t. some class of maps?


Comment: @Sergei. "standard" = "found in literature"

Comment: @Elizabeth, you are right, that very much like your question, but I need to work with particular choice of metric and if there is one people already use I would be happy to use the same (especially if it already has a name).

Comment: I'm guessing you've considered this because it is one of the first things that came up in a Google search, but how about section 3 of http://www.jstor.org/stable/2047675?  I don't know if it is relevant because they use the term "one point compactification" in an unusual way, but perhaps for proper spaces they are the same?  

Comment: Elizabeth's idea won't work: as then small open balls about infinity will just be the point infinity; large open balls (i.e. of radius >1) will be the whole space.  What we need (at least) is that small open balls about infinity have closed and bounded (i.e. compact) complements.

Comment: Anton: you may want to redefine "standard" again for the possible construction. By your first definition, your possible construction is definitely standard.

Comment: @Willie, where did you see it? (It is different from the one you see in the paper.)

Comment: @Anton Petrunin Why $\hat d$ is  a metric?

Answer (score 1):

I will make this an answer although it is just a follow-up to the comment of LK

The recent names in this (but referring back to Bonk and Kleiner) are Stephen Buckley and David Herron, for proper spaces their one-point extension $\hat{X}$ is the one-point compactification, see pages 4 and 8 in

[PDF]
METRIC SPACE INVERSIONS, QUASIHYPERBOLIC DISTANCE, AND UNIFORM SPACES
File Format: PDF/Adobe Acrobat - Quick View
by SM Buckley - 2008 - Cited by 3 - Related articles
In a certain sense, inversion is dual to sphericalization. ... point compactification. All of the properties of dp mentioned above also hold for their con- ...

https://eprints.nuim.ie/1610/1/BuckleyMetricSpace.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard metric for the one-point compactification of the complex plane, given by stereographic projection of the sphere onto the plane.  But of course if you translate the plane first, the result is different, so is even that an example of what you want?

Comment: Do you see a simple way to generalize it to proper spaces?